# IronPython and ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Breaking up several questions I asked in
[http://answers.ros.org/question/45234/multiplatform-dotnet-ros-workflow-redistribution-issues/]

So issue #1: I have failed to load roslib into IronPython. Does anyone know if this can be solved? Here is my execution. I first run it with python, so you see it works, things are set up correctly. However, with ipy it doesn't find roslib.

```
Tiago-Ribeiros-MacBook-Pro:~ tiagoribeiro$ roscd SimplePerception/
Tiago-Ribeiros-MacBook-Pro:SimplePerception tiagoribeiro$ python nodes/SimplePerceptionEffector.py
/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ros_comm-1.8.12-py2.7.egg/rospy/topics.py:758: UserWarning: '\Perception\SimplePerception' is not a legal ROS graph resource name. This may cause problems with other ROS tools
[INFO] [WallTime: 1349574242.992873] hello world 1349574242.99
[INFO] [WallTime: 1349574243.994326] hello world 1349574243.99
^C

Tiago-Ribeiros-MacBook-Pro:SimplePerception tiagoribeiro$ ipy nodes/SimplePerctionEffector.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "nodes/SimplePerceptionEffector.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: No module named roslib
Tiago-Ribeiros-MacBook-Pro:SimplePerception tiagoribeiro$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45260/ironpython-and-ros/) by [TiagoRibeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3310/tiagoribeiro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-10-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-10-08**:
Does ipy respect the PYTHONPATH environment variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can probably do something similar to:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"c:\path\to\ros")
```

But you could also use the roscs (ROS C#) library directly. We use the rosjava library, by turning it into DLLs through IKVM. We use rosjava because it doesn't have any other dependencies, whereas roscs depends on Ubuntu.

---

Originally posted by [Doug Blank](https://answers.ros.org/users/3381/doug-blank/) with karma: 26 on 2013-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1